# Do we have any character limit for the message we display in toast pop up using force:showToast?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, toast

do we have any character to the message attribute in force:showToast interface? How many charcters can we display if there is a limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no hard-coded limit. Instead, you'll end up scrolling off the screen. How much text you'll be able to show will depend on your screen resolution, browser window size, and zoom/scale settings, if any.

[image: Very Long Toast Message]

[image: Even Longer Toast Message]